# Телеграмм бот. Ошибка: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Получаю ошибку:

> Task exception was never retrieved future: 
> <Task finished name='Task-42' coro=<ads_every_minute() done, defined at C:\Users\PC\Desktop\avparser-sliv\bot.py:93> exception=TypeError("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable")> 
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\avparser-sliv\bot.py", line 103, in ads_every_minute new_ad_url = get_ad_data(ads_url)[-1] 
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

бот сразу же перестает работать после нее.

Обычно это происходит после часа работы, вероятнее всего ошибка может быть в этой части кода:

```
async def ads_every_minute(user_id):
    while True:
        ads_users_list = get_all_users_ads(user_id)
        if len(ads_users_list) >= 1:
            for ads in ads_users_list:
                ads_url = str(ads).split("'")[1]
                tracked_url_title = get_requested_page_title(ads_url)
                old_ad = get_old_ad_from_db(user_id, tracked_url=ads_url)
                old_ad_url = str(old_ad).split("'")[1]
                new_ad_url = get_ad_data(ads_url)[-1]
                new_ad_data = (user_id, ads_url, new_ad_url,tracked_url_title)
                if new_ad_url != old_ad_url:
                    delete_old_data(user_id, tracked_url=ads_url)
                    write_url_on_db(new_ad_data)

                    await bot.send_message( user_id, f'{build_nice_message(ads_url)}',disable_web_page_preview=True)
                else:
                    print('Обновлений нет ')

        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(40, 90))
```

Comment: а что у вас там на картинке написано?

Comment: Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-42' coro=<ads_every_minute() done, defined at C:\Users\PC\Desktop\avparser-sliv\bot.py:93> exception=TypeError("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\avparser-sliv\bot.py", line 103, in ads_every_minute
    new_ad_url = get_ad_data(ads_url)[-1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Изменил пост, добавив часть кода, где вероятнее всего может быть ошибка

Comment: @DmtAkasha2, добавьте ошибку в вопрос, комментарий плохо подходит для такого :) Судя по ошибке, у вас функция `get_ad_data(ads_url)` вернула `None`

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка не в этой функции. Ошибка содержиться в функции get_ad_data, которая при каких-то входных данных возвращает None.

Ниже вариант кода, в котором пропускаются входные данные, при которых get_ad_data возвращает пустое значение.

```
async def ads_every_minute(user_id):
    while True:
        ads_users_list = get_all_users_ads(user_id)
        if len(ads_users_list) >= 1:
            for ads in ads_users_list:
                ads_url = str(ads).split("'")[1]
                tracked_url_title = get_requested_page_title(ads_url)
                old_ad = get_old_ad_from_db(user_id, tracked_url=ads_url)
                old_ad_url = str(old_ad).split("'")[1]

                full_new_ad_url = get_ad_data(ads_url)
                # Записали полный вариант полученных данных

                if full_new_ad_url:
                    new_ad_url = fill_new_ad_url[-1]
                else:
                    print('get_ad_data вызывает ошибку при входных данных:', ads_url)
                    continue

                new_ad_data = (user_id, ads_url, new_ad_url,tracked_url_title)
                if new_ad_url != old_ad_url:
                    delete_old_data(user_id, tracked_url=ads_url)
                    write_url_on_db(new_ad_data)

                    await bot.send_message( user_id, f'{build_nice_message(ads_url)}',disable_web_page_preview=True)
                else:
                    print('Обновлений нет ')

        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(40, 90))
```

Comment: Вы так на все вызовы всех функций будете писать if?